# OpenResty: not found 'socket' module

Tags: lua, openresty

I install  lua `socket` module by run the following command:

```
apt install  lua-socket
```

When use `local socket = require('socket')` in OpenResty config, I got the following error:

```
module 'socket' not found:
no field package.preload['socket']
no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/socket.ljbc'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/socket/init.ljbc'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/socket.ljbc'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/socket/init.ljbc'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/socket.lua'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/socket/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/socket.lua'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/socket/init.lua'
no file './socket.lua'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta3/socket.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/socket.lua'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/socket/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/socket.so'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/lualib/socket.so'
no file './socket.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
no file '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib/lua/5.1/socket.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

OpenResty Version: 1.19.3.1

How can use `socket` module in OpenResty?

Comment: I'm also interested, I need this :/

Answer (score 0):

I think https://github.com/thibaultCha/lua-resty-socket should be used in openresty ecosystem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31889323)